# Using Express To Create A Server For Webhook - Set Up Error - Invalid or Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn about Facebook messaging bots because I think they're neat. I've been following [this Medium article](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-create-your-very-own-facebook-messenger-bot-with-dialogflow-and-node-js-in-just-one-day-f5f2f5792be5) that's a tutorial and I've gotten to the part where you call the index.js.

**node index.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Webhook server is listening, port 3000'));
```

When I do this I receive an error stating that I have an unexpected token. I am not sure how to react to it.

JSON File:

```
    {
  "name": "bot-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

The error I receive:

```
C:\Users\jackt\Bot Tutorial\index.js:2
const app = express();
            ^

ReferenceError: express is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jackt\Bot Tutorial\index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

**Directory Structure:**

[image: Directory Struct]

Comment: give contents of index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.js can you include

```
const express = require('express');
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have copied the code from the article along with the curly single quotes: `‘`

Change them to regular single quotes: `'`

Comment: So that was a problem but did not fix everything. It now says that express is not defined.

Comment: If you don't know, I'll just mark your answer as correct since you did fix the original error

Comment: Raja figured it out, so Ill give him the points if thats cool